# Why does function apply complain about long lists?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, apply, sieve-of-eratosthenes, wheel-factorization

As part of some [Eulerian travails](http://projecteuler.net), I'm trying to code a [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) with a factorization wheel. My code so far is:

```
(defun ring (&rest content)
"Returns a circular list containing the elements in content.
 The returned list starts with the first element of content."
   (setf (cdr (last content)) content))

(defun factorization-wheel (lst)
"Returns a circular list containing a factorization 
 wheel using the list of prime numbers in lst"
   (let ((circumference (apply #'* lst)))
     (loop for i from 1 to circumference
           unless (some #'(lambda (x) (zerop (mod i x))) lst)
             collect i into wheel
           finally (return (apply #'ring 
                             (maplist 
                                 #'(lambda (x) ; Takes exception to long lists (?!)
                                     (if (cdr x)
                                         (- (cadr x) (car x))
                                         (- circumference (car x) -1)))
                                 wheel))))))

(defun eratosthenes (n &optional (wheel (ring 4 2)))
"Returns primes up to n calculated using
 a Sieve of Eratosthenes and a factorization wheel"
   (let* ((candidates (loop with s = 1
                            for i in wheel
                            collect (setf s (+ i s))
                            until (> s n))))
       (maplist #'(lambda (x) 
                    (if (> (expt (car x) 2) n)     
                        (return-from eratosthenes candidates))
                    (delete-if 
                        #'(lambda (y) (zerop (mod y (car x)))) 
                        (cdr x))) 
                candidates)))
```

I got the following result for wheels longer than 6 elements. I didn't really understand why:

```
21 > (factorization-wheel '(2 3 5 7 11 13))
(16 2 4 6 2 6 4 2 4 6 6 2 6 4 2 6 4 6 8 4 ...)
21 > (factorization-wheel '(2 3 5 7 11 13 17))
> Error: Too many arguments.
> While executing: FACTORIZATION-WHEEL, in process listener(1).
```

The algorithm seems to be working OK otherwise and churns out primes with wheels having 6 or fewer elements.

Apparently `apply` or `ring` turn up their noses when long lists are passed to them.

But shouldn't the list count as a single argument? I admit I'm thoroughly flummoxed. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: It's amazingly popular to miss the main point (and the beauty) of this algorithm. The Sieve of Eratosthenes is based on repeated addition; it does not test for divisibility using `mod` or any other method. (See e.g. [this paper](https://www.cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf).)

Comment: Thanks for the great link! My `factorization-wheel` is crap too, so I guess I'll just start over.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

ANSI Common Lisp allows implementations to constrain the maximum number of arguments which can be passed to a function. This limit is given by [call-arguments-limit](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm) can be as small as 50.

For functions which behave like algebraic group operators obeying the
associative property (`+`, `list`, and others), we can get around the limit by using `reduce` to decimate the input list while treating the function as binary.

For instance to add a large list of numbers: `(reduce #'+ list)` rather than `(apply #'+ list)`.

#### Notes on `reduce`

In Common Lisp, `reduce` will appear to work even if the list is empty. Few other languages give you this, and it doesn't actually come from `reduce`: it won't work for all functions. But with `+` we can write `(reduce #'+ nil)` and it calculates zero, just like `(apply #'+ nil)`.

Why is that? Because the `+` function can be called with zero arguments, and when called with zero arguments, it yields the identity element for the additive group: `0`.  This dovetails with the `reduce` function.

In some other languages the `fold` or `reduce` function must be given an initial seed value (like `0`), or else a nonempty list. If it is given neither, it is an error.

The Common Lisp `reduce`, if it is given an empty list and no `:initial-value`, will call the kernel function with no arguments, and use the return value as the initial value. Since that value is then the only value (the list is empty), that value is returned.

Watch out for functions with special rules for the leftmost argument. For instance:

```
(apply #'- '(1)) -> -1  ;; same as (- 1), unary minus semantics.

(reduce #'- '(1)) -> 1  ;; what?
```

What's going on is that when `reduce` is given a one-element list, it just returns the element without calling the function.

Basically it is founded on the mathematical assumption mentioned above that if no `:initial-value` is supplied then `f` is expected to support `(f) -> i`, where `i` is some identity element in relation to `f`, so that `(f i x) -> x`. This is used as the initial value when reducing the singleton list, `(reduce #'f (list x)) -> (f (f) x) -> (f i x) -> x`.

The `-` function doesn't obey these rules. `(- a 0)` means "subtract zero from `a`" and so yields `a`, whereas `(- a)` is the additive inverse of `a`, probably for purely pragmatic, notational reasons (namely, not making Lisp programmers write `(- 0 a)` just to flip a sign, just for the sake of having `-` behave more consistently under `reduce` and `apply`).  The `-` function also may not be called with zero arguments.

If we want to take a list of numbers and subtract them all from some value `x`, the pattern for that is:

```
(reduce #'- list-of-numbers :initial-value x)
```

Comment: Indeed I managed to solve the problem by creating a `ring-list` function that takes the whole list as an argument. I'll probably redo this from scratch though.

Comment: *idempotence* though means something else, namely [ƒ(ƒ(x)) ≡ ƒ(x)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence). using `x` for `f/[x]` comes from the definition of the fold (`/`), i.e. ``f/[x,...ys...] == x `f` (f/ys)`` hence ``f/[x] == f/[x,...[]...] = x `f` (f/[]) == x`` since `f/[]` is supposed to be the identity element for `f` (e.g. 0 for `+`, and 1 for `*`), as you rightly point out.

Comment: @WillNess Thanks; I fixed the misuse of "idempotent".

Comment: I tweaked it; feel free to revert.