# Lisp: Add respective elements of a list of lists

Tags: nested, lisp, common-lisp

Let's say I have a list:

```
((1 2 3) (8 4 7) (41 79 30) (0 8 5))
```

I want to do this:

```
(1+8+41+0 2+4+79+8 3+7+30+5) = (50 93 45)
```

I've found an ugly solution:

```
(defun nested+ (lst)
  (let ((acc nil))
    (dotimes (i (length (first lst)))
      (push (apply #'+ (mapcar #'(lambda (a) (nth i a)) lst)) acc))
    (reverse acc)))
```

It seems to work for my purposes, but I guess it is slow and un-lispy. What's the proper way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The naive solution would be

```
(apply #'mapcar #'+ list)
```

However, as already pointed out e.g. [here by stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34194355/why-does-function-apply-complain-about-long-lists) and [here by LispWorks](http://www.lispworks.com/kb/4fbc798cb17237ca852566da005fcc79.html), the `call-arguments-limit` of (in the worst case) 50 arguments applies to functions called by `apply`. And `reduce` is suggested instead.

Thus, I suggest:

```
(defun sum-all (lists)
  (reduce #'(lambda (l1 l2) (mapcar #'+ l1 l2)) lists))
```

And indeed

```
(sum-all '((1 2 3) (8 4 7) (41 79 30) (0 8 5)))
;; (50 93 45)
```

Comment: This is a really nice answer.

Answer (score 8):

One option is `(apply #'mapcar #'+ list)`. Mapcar will consume as many lists as you give it and stop when it reaches the end of the shortest list.

Comment: This is a neat answer but can fail mysteriously for long lists (I am sure Xach knows this, but the person asking may not).

Comment: you are talking about `call-arguments-limit` of functions - the number of maximum arguments a function can take, which is implementation-dependent and should be at least 50. In my sbcl I see it has the value of 536870911 and clisp 4096, so quite many ...

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: in ABCL - Common Lisp on the JVM - it's just 50. Not that many.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: even in CLISP a 4096-element list is not very long!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to loop over your list of lists:

```
(defun sum-all (lists)
  (loop
    for list in lists
    for result = (copy-list list) then (map-into result #'+ result list)
    finally (return result)))
```

During the first iteration, the first list is copied. The resulting list is then used in successive iterations to hold the respective sums. At the end of the iteration, that result list is returned.